# How to watch and reload ts-node when TypeScript files change

Tags: typescript, development-environment, nodemon

I'm trying to run a dev server with TypeScript and an Angular application without transpiling ts files every time.

What I found is that I *can* run `.ts` files with `ts-node` but I want also to watch `.ts` files and reload my app/server. An example of this is the command `gulp watch`.

Answer (score 1018, accepted):

You can now simply `npm install --save-dev ts-node nodemon` and then run `nodemon` with a `.ts` file and it will Just Work:

```
nodemon app.ts
```

---

Previous versions:

I was struggling with the same thing for my development environment until I noticed that `nodemon`'s API allows us to change its default behaviour in order to execute a custom command.

For example, for the most recent version of `nodemon`:

```bash
nodemon --watch "src/**" --ext "ts,json" --ignore "src/**/*.spec.ts" --exec "ts-node src/index.ts"
```

Or create a `nodemon.json` file with the following content:

```bash
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts,json",
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "exec": "ts-node ./src/index.ts"      // or "npx ts-node src/index.ts"
}
```

and then run `nodemon` with no arguments.

By virtue of doing this, you'll be able to live-reload a `ts-node` process without having to worry about the underlying implementation.

---

And with even older versions of `nodemon`:

```
nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --ignore 'src/**/*.spec.ts' --exec 'ts-node' src/index.ts
```

Or even better: externalize nodemon's config to a `nodemon.json` file with the following content, and then just run `nodemon`, as Sandokan suggested:

```
{
  "watch": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "exec": "ts-node ./index.ts"
}
```

Comment: if `index.ts` is a express instance, how can i kill it and restart

Comment: @elaijuh in theory this same command should do the trick, when nodemon is configured to execute a custom command (in this case ts-node) instead of the default node command, it will shut down the process and start a new one each time it finds a change on the watch expression minus the ignore expression :)

Comment: you can also create a nodemon.json file with all the mentioned options in it like this: `{
"watch": ["src/**/*.ts"],
"ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
"exec": "ts-node  ./app-server.ts"
}` and just type `nodemon`

Comment: I made the mistake of adding `./` before the folder names and it broke. This worked for me: `{ "verbose": true, "watch": ["server/**/*.ts"], "ext": "ts js json", "ignore": ["server/**/*.spec.ts"], "exec": "ts-node index.ts" }`. And  command line: `nodemon --watch server/**/*.ts --ignore server/**/*.spec.ts --verbose --exec ts-node index.ts`

Comment: I would just like mention, that you also have to set the `ext` in the config file, so its look for ts changes. My config file look like this: `{
  "watch": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "ext": "ts js json",
  "_exec": "node dist/startup.js",
  "exec": "ts-node src/startup.ts"
}`

Comment: For windows users you will need to make the exec command an array for pathing issues:
 `"exec": "ts-node ./src/index.ts"` becomes =>
`"exec": ["ts-node", "src/index.ts"]`

Comment: I'm using grunt-ts with nodemon, what is the difference?.. Should I use grunt-ts or ts-node..?

Comment: @HeberLZ `nomdemon.json` should be `nodemon.json`, i think

Comment: nodemon.json file makes things easier, thanks for sharing.

Comment: still the best practice?

Comment: I am getting (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import * as express from 'express';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

looks like it is not taking es6 code, how can I add es6?

Comment: I have the same config as you but it only refreshes when i update index.ts and not any of the javascript files in src.

Comment: `nodemon` and t`s-node` will become very slow if the typescript project goes too big. `ts-node-dev` can not reload when a ts file only contains interfaces got changes.

Comment: On Windows machines, DON'T use single quotes in your package.json. Replacing those with `\"` makes the script run fine: `"nodemon --watch \"./src/**/*.ts\" -r dotenv/config --exec \"ts-node\" src/index.ts"`

Comment: with first `nodemon.json` version I had to run `nodemon -e ts`, now with updated config file this option is not required.

Comment: I've tried running `npm install --save-dev ts-node nodemon` then `nodemon src/index.ts` but still get the error:  `ts-node is not recognized as an internal or external command...`. Is there a reason it's still not?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me out of the box. Fortunately, nodemon can be easily configured. Try `npx nodemon -h` for a list of options. This is what worked for me: `nodemon --watch src --ext ts,js`

Comment: Simply running `nodemon app.ts` didn't recompile on changes to .js files. I had to use the more verbose version and include `js` in the `--ext` flag.

Answer (score 297):

I've dumped `nodemon` and `ts-node` in favor of a much better alternative, `ts-node-dev`
https://github.com/whitecolor/ts-node-dev

Just run `ts-node-dev src/index.ts`

[EDIT]
Since I wrote this answer, nodemon has improved a lot, the required config is much lighter now and performance is much better. I currently use both (on different projects, obviously), and am satisfied with both.

Comment: And why is this better?

Comment: It's faster, and automatically detects which files need to be watched, no config needed.

Comment: This is the best (if not the only) option for ts-node, especially for larger projects. It doesn't recompile all files from scratch, but does an incremental compilation, like `tsc --watch`.

Comment: for me, I have to add  "ts-node-dev": "ts-node-dev" in the script array of package.json and then do npm run ts-node-dev server.ts to make it work

Comment: in my case, this literally 10 times faster than `nodemon` with `ts-node`. Thank you!

Comment: So I literally just have `"start": "ts-node-dev src"`. No need for babel, nodemon, or any of the config that comes with it. Everything is handled for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, no longer maintained and stopped working for me. Had to revert to `nodemon`.

Comment: It is very fast. I just added it as follows: "start": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpileOnly src/index.ts"

Comment: This litereally made me went from 5-6 seconds to reload to ~0.5 seconds, changed my whole experience

Comment: very fast and seems to work really well, however it seems to ignore all environment variables and has some hidden behavior handling env for you.

Comment: nodemon + ts-node without config worked for me. Simple command: `nodemon src/index.ts`

Comment: fast is an understatement for this... thanks a lot bro... I was using the shi**y nodemon for so long

Comment: the debugger wont attach with ts-node-dev, is there a fix?

Comment: Somethings wrong with this package, I highly advise that no one downloads this globally. When I installed it globally, I could no longer run react native with expo. Something like that shouldn't happen.

Comment: `ts-node-dev` is a nice idea but it has a *lot* of problems. It's really just not reliable enough for real-world use. The maintainer seems underequipped to deal with the issues, unfortunately. Back to `nodemon` I go...

Comment: Went from nodemon to ts-node-dev on Windows, as a reload after file changes always crashed the ts-node process, with "port already in use".

Comment: Its better because works like nodemon and has others setup. Theoretically, is faster too.

Comment: I used this, but eventually I realized it's having major issues with picking up changed files. Saving a file, process is restarted, but somehow old files are still being used. Super annoying. Not an issue with accepted answer.‍♂️

Answer (score 96):

### Summary of options from other answers

- [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) plus [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) is pretty stable but needs to be explicitly configured and is somewhat slow
- [node-dev](https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev) plus [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) requires much less configuration than nodemon but is still slow
- [ts-node-dev](https://github.com/wclr/ts-node-dev) is fast but [unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979489/how-to-watch-and-reload-ts-node-when-typescript-files-change#comment121068696_50528031)

**Note** that `tsx` (which uses ESBuild under the hood) and `swc` don't do type checking; this should be acceptable since most editors have type checking built-in, and type checking should still be part of your build process. You can also do type checking separately alongside your tests or as a pre-push hook via [`tsc --noEmit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmit).

### (Recommended) [tsx](https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx)

> ⓘ TL;DR: fastest with minimal configuration

As of 2023-02-01, [tsx](https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx) seems to be the best combination of speed and minimal configuration:

1. Install tsx

   ```
   npm install --save-dev tsx
   ```
2. Update your package.json, e.g.

   ```json
   "scripts: {
     "dev": "tsx watch src/index.ts",
   ```
3. Run it

   ```
   npm run dev
   ```

   (Adjust these steps if you just want to install tsx globally and run it directly)

### Alternative 1: nodemon/node-dev + ts-node + swc

> ⓘ TL;DR: as fast as tsx but with more configuration

An alternative option that combines the reliability of nodemon/node-dev with the speed of ts-node-dev is to use ts-node with [`swc`](https://swc.rs/), a TypeScript-compatible transpiler implemented in Rust which is an "order of magnitude faster" than the TypeScript transpiler.

1. Install nodemon or node-dev (whichever you prefer)

   - nodemon

     ```
     npm install --save-dev nodemon
     ```
   - node-dev

     ```
     npm install --save-dev node-dev
     ```
2. Set up ts-node with swc integration

   https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#swc-1

   1. Install necessary packages

      ```
      npm install --save-dev ts-node @swc/core @swc/helpers regenerator-runtime
      ```
   2. Add this to tsconfig.json

      ```json
        "ts-node": {
          "swc": true
        }
      ```
3. Run nodemon or node-dev, e.g

   ```
   nodemon --watch src src/index.ts
   ```

   or:

   ```
   node-dev src/index.ts
   ```

### Alternative 2: nodemon/node-dev + ts-node transpileOnly

> ⓘ TL;DR: fast, reliable

Here's an alternative that's slower than the previous option because it uses the standard TypeScript transpiler, but in my testing it's still faster than nodemon/node-dev + ts-node.

Basically it's the same as the previous option but without `swc`. It's faster than out-of-the-box ts-node by disabling type checking (see notes above regarding why this should be acceptable).

1. Install nodemon/node-dev as above
2. Install ts-node

   ```
   npm install --save-dev ts-node
   ```
3. Modify your tsconfig.json to enable `transpileOnly` for ts-node

   ```json
     "ts-node": {
       "transpileOnly": true
     }
   ```
4. Call nodemon/node-dev as above

### Alternative 3: nodemon + tsc --incremental

> ⓘ TL;DR: fast, reliable, type checking, more finicky

This is nearly the same speed as the previous alternative. The only real advantage of this over the other options is that it does type checking.

In terms of downsides, it can be a bit more finicky; in my testing, I'm using `dotenv` to pick up my `.env` file for local development. But depending how your `tsc` build is configured in tsconfig.json, you may have to do some acrobatics to get it working.

But it's good to have options, so here it is:

1. Install nodemon as above

   (It's possible that this may work with node-dev as well, but I didn't see an `exec` option for node-dev)
2. Configure tsconfig.json to transpile your TypeScript to JavaScript

   In particular, `noEmit` should not be set to `true`
3. Configure nodemon to run the TypeScript compiler to do an [incremental transpilation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#incremental) any time a TypeScript file is changed, e.g.

   ```json
   "dev": "nodemon -e ts --watch src .env --exec \"tsc --incremental && node src/index.js\"",
   ```

   You can even remove `--incremental` to further simplify it, but it will end up being much slower, comparable to nodemon/node-dev + ts-node.

Comment: If you install `nodemon` locally, you cannot run `nodemon` on cmd. Instead, install it `globally` with `-g`.

Comment: You can still run it without it being installed globally (e.g. `node_modules/.bin/nodemon`), but given that I almost always need to provide flags to nodemon, it's much more convenient to add a script in package.json that runs nodemon with all the flags I need (as in the example in *Alternative 3*). That also makes it more convenient when working with multiple projects; you can just call `npm run dev` and not have to remember how each project needs to be configured. Of course you're more than welcome to install it globally if that suits your fancy.

Comment: What do you mean by "type checking should still be part of your build process". And how would I include type checking in my build process?

Comment: @thegoodhunter-9115 The tools recommended by the answers on this page are for local development. But for production, it's generally recommended to transpile the TypeScript to JavaScript, which is the "build" step. If you're using the TypeScript compiler (`tsc`), it does type checking by default ([actually I don't think there's any way to turn it off](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29651)). Since you might not want to wait until build time to find out if there are any type errors, you could also use `tsc` to do type checking as part of your testing process or as a pre-push hook.

Comment: `tsx` doesn't support `emitDecoratorMetadata` for now

Answer (score 78):

Here's an alternative to the HeberLZ's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37979548/6673479), using npm scripts.

My `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "nodemon -e ts -w ./src -x npm run watch:serve",
    "watch:serve": "ts-node --inspect src/index.ts"
  },
```

- `-e` flag sets the extenstions to look for,
- `-w` sets the watched directory,
- `-x` executes the script.

`--inspect` in the `watch:serve` script is actually a node.js flag, it just enables debugging protocol.

Comment: Also be sure to have typescript locally installed for the project. Otherwise the error you might get is not very clear.

Comment: I think it should be `ts-node --inspect -- src/index.ts` now due to [this](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/552).

Comment: This approach seems to generate considerable superfluous output.

Comment: `-e ts -w ./src` did the trick for me - this worked with a loopback4 CLI generated project

Comment: I get `Error: Unknown or unexpected option: --inspect`. It seems that `ts-node` does not have the flag.

Comment: @Timo looks like starting from [v5.0.0](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/releases/tag/v5.0.0) for advanced node.js flags (like `--inspect` in this case) you need to run ts-node as `node -r ts-node/register` command.

Comment: I also had to use the `--legacy-watch` flag to make autoreload possible. Any idea why?

Answer (score 58):

This works for me:

```
nodemon src/index.ts
```

Apparently thanks to since this pull request: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/pull/1552

Comment: This works for me too but how? Seems kind of magical. What's compiling the typescript? I don't have `ts-node` installed.

Comment: @d512 Are you sure it's not in your `node_modules/`? For me it fails if I don't have it.

Comment: This indeed does require `ts-node` to be installed. Running this command without `ts-node` will result in an `failed to start process, "ts-node" exec not found` error. You likely had this as a leftover artifact in `node_modules`. That being said, this solution is much nicer since it doesn't require additional config.

Comment: Install ts-node globally: `npm install -g ts-node`

Answer (score 21):

you could use [ts-node-dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev)

It restarts target node process when any of required files changes (as standard node-dev) but shares Typescript compilation process between restarts.

**Install**

```
yarn add ts-node-dev --dev
```

and your package.json could be like this

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "tsc": "tsc",
  "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpileOnly ./src/index.ts",
  "prod": "tsc && node ./build/index.js"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the easiest way I found to enable auto reload with my node server.

Answer (score 20):

Specifically for this issue I've created the `tsc-watch` library. you can find it on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-watch).

Obvious use case would be:

`tsc-watch server.ts --outDir ./dist --onSuccess "node ./dist/server.js"`

Comment: How would this work in the case of an express or koa server since it doesn't actually kill the previous node instance?

Comment: 'tsc-watch' kills and restarts the process for you.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Not sure what the purpose of ts-node-dev is, but I couldn't get it to report typescript errors. After spending hours trying to get it working, I tried tsc-watch, and it worked like a charm!

Comment: @gilamran in the documentation of your package there is a typo: `"[...] similar to nodemon but for TypeCcript."`:)

Answer (score 13):

Add `"watch": "nodemon --exec ts-node -- ./src/index.ts"` to `scripts` section of your `package.json`.

Answer (score 10):

I would prefer to not use ts-node and always run from dist folder.
To do that, just setup your package.json with default config:

```
....
"main": "dist/server.js",
"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc",
  "prestart": "npm run build",
  "start": "node .",
  "dev": "nodemon"
},
....
```

and then add **nodemon.json** config file:

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "exec": "npm restart"
}
```

Here, i use **"exec": "npm restart"**

So all ts file will re-compile to js file and then restart the server.

To run while in dev environment,

```bash
npm run dev
```

Using this setup I will always run from the distributed files and no need for ts-node.

Comment: Like walking on glass. But an alternative, non-the-less

Answer (score 9):

i did with

```
"start": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --ignore 'src/**/*.spec.ts' --exec ts-node src/index.ts"
```

and yarn start.. ts-node not like 'ts-node'

Answer (score 9):

### Standard Approach

Starting from Node.js version `v16.19.0`, the
[CLI](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--watch) API introduces the
`--watch` option, eliminating the need for additional dependencies like
[nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon).

For TypeScript execution, use well-established package
[ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node). Here's
configuration example:

```
// package.json
{
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "node --watch --loader=ts-node/esm ./src/app.ts"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "ts-node": "~10.9.0"
    }
}
```

### Non-Standard Approach

Alternatively, you might consider [tsx](https://github.com/privatenumber/tsx),
although it's not as mature as ts-node.

Keep in mind that tsx currently lacks support for `emitDecoratorMetadata` a
crucial feature for many projects that need decorators. Despite this drawback, tsx offers faster
compilation (esbuild backend):

```
// package.json
{
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "tsx watch ./src/app.ts"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "tsx": "~4.6.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Lots of errors with this for example ```Caused by:
    unknown field `noInterop`, expected `resolveFully` at line 1 column 433```

Comment: Please give additional context. What specifically do you mean by "Lots of errors", share your project setup, tooling you are transitioning from, etc....

Comment: @OliverDixon This is because ts-node doesn't properly support the latest version of swc/core. you need to override the version of swc/core to 1.3.82 (at the time of writing). in `package.json` add
`"resolutions": {
    "@swc/core": "1.3.82"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "@swc/core": "1.3.82"
  }`
(DO NOT copy versions used in this github issue link, use 1.3.82) https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/2070#issuecomment-1741500105

Answer (score 7):

Another way could be to compile the code first in watch mode with `tsc -w` and then use nodemon over javascript. This method is similar in speed to ts-node-dev and has the advantage of being more production-like.

```sh
 "scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "dev": "nodemon dist/index.js"
  },
```

Comment: Or just `"dev": "( tsc -w & ) && nodemon dist/index.js"`.

Comment: This was a great answer for me. Simple and easy, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

> The first step - Install the below packages in deDependencies

```
npm i -D @types/express @types/node nodemon ts-node tsc typescript
```

or using yarn

```
yarn add -D @types/express @types/node nodemon ts-node tsc typescript
```

> The second step - using this configuration in your tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', 'ES2021', or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "ES2017"
    ] /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */,
    "sourceMap": true /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */,
    "outDir": "./dist" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    "rootDir": "./src" /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */,

    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

> The third step - using these scripts in your package.json file

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./dist/server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon -L ./src/server.ts && tsc -w"
},
```

Answer (score 5):

add this to your package.json file

```
scripts {
"dev": "nodemon --watch '**/*.ts' --exec 'ts-node' index.ts"
}
```

and to make this work you also need to install ts-node as dev-dependency

```sh
yarn add ts-node -D
```

run `yarn dev` to start the dev server

Answer (score 3):

**STEP 1:** You can simple install `nodemon` and `ts-node` *(skip if you already done)*

```
npm install --save-dev nodemon ts-node
```

**STEP 2:** You can configure the start script in package.json

```
"start": "nodemon ./src/app.ts"
```

As now nodemon automatically identify the typescript from the project now and use `ts-node` command by itself. Use `npm start` and it will automatically compile/watch and reload.

If you get any errors like typescript module not found in the project. simple use this command in the project folder.

```
npm link typescript
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this error : `code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'` i needed the esm support, so if you want `ES6` support you can try bellow commands

`npm i -D ts-node nodemon`

in package.json add below script :

`"dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node-esm ./src/index.ts"`

Answer (score 1):

Just update these 3 packages

```
nodemon, ts-node, typescript
yarn global add nodemon ts-node typescript
```

or

```
npm install -g nodemon ts-node typescript
```

and now you can run this, problem solved

```
nodemon <filename>.ts
```

Comment: Please add your comments or instructions outside of your code. That will be more understandable and readable.

Answer (score 1):

## Clear logs of the console after changing

### Javascript:

```
"start": "nodemon -x \"cls && node\" index.js",
```

### Typescript:

```
"start": "nodemon -x \"cls && ts-node\" index.ts",
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to install Nodemon and run: "nodemon --exec npx ts-node --esm test.ts"

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues when using `"type": "module"` in `package.json` (described in https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1007) use the following config:

```json
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts,json",
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "exec": "node --loader ts-node/esm --experimental-specifier-resolution ./src/index.ts"
}
```

or in the command line

```sh
nodemon --watch "src/**" --ext "ts,json" --ignore "src/**/*.spec.ts" --exec "node --loader ts-node/esm --experimental-specifier-resolution src/index.ts"
```

Answer (score 0):

add `--poll` options on your package.json

The `--poll` option in ts-node-dev tells it to check the source code files for changes by periodically looking at them, instead of waiting for the file system to report changes. This ensures that changes to the files are always detected, even on file systems that don't report changes reliably.

```
   "start": "ts-node-dev --poll src/index.ts"
```

Answer (score 0):

With **[ts-node-dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev)** version 2.0.0+ you can use:

```
ts-node-dev --respawn ./src/index.ts
```

*Note: If you get *"command not found"* error, then you can run it directly from node-modules like so:

```
./node_modules/.bin/ts-node-dev --respawn ./src/index.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also another option if you'd like to forego just running both tsc and the payload in parallel, and want them to be more coupled together without needing to switch to a complicated tsc wrapper or alternative. You could also write a Node.js script to wait for the TypeScript compiler to complete building and then start your process when the build is complete.

This is what I wrote for one of my projects (this needs the `tree-kill` package installed):

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

import { spawn } from 'node:child_process';
import { join } from 'node:path';
import { createInterface } from 'node:readline';
import process from 'node:process';
import kill from 'tree-kill';

const cwd = process.cwd();
const tscConfigPath = join(cwd, 'tsconfig.build.json');
const tscArgs = ['tsc', '--build', '--watch', '--pretty', tscConfigPath];
const command = process.argv.slice(2);

// adjust params above as necessary

const tsc = spawn('yarn', tscArgs, { // change if not using yarn
  stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', 'inherit'],
  cwd,
});

let proc;

const startCommand = () => {
  proc && kill(proc.pid);
  proc = spawn(command[0], command.slice(1), { stdio: 'inherit', cwd });
};

const rl = createInterface({
  input: tsc.stdout,
  terminal: false,
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
  console.log(line);
  if (line.includes('Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.')) {
    startCommand();
  }
});

tsc.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log('tsc exited with code', code);
  proc && kill(proc.pid);
  process.exit(code);
});

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  kill(tsc.pid);
  proc && kill(proc.pid);
  process.exit(0);
});

process.on('exit', () => {
  kill(tsc.pid);
  proc && kill(proc.pid);
});
```

I use it in other packages in my monorepo like this in the package.json manifest:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start:dev": "run-on-tsc-build yarn node dist/main.js"
}
```

It works by waiting to see the "Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes." message from Typescript and then running the given command.

Answer (score -1):

With [`nodemon`](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) and [`ts-node`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node):

```sh
nodemon --watch source --ext ts,json --exec "node --loader ts-node/esm ./source/index.ts"
```