# Cannot read property 'on' of undefined in electron javascript

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to run this code but every time I am getting this error message. First I installed `npm` globally. Then I installed it within my app but still getting same error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined at
>   Object. (H:\electric\main.js:12:4) at Object.
>   (H:\electric\main.js:63:3) at Module._compile (module.js:571:32) at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10) at Module.load
>   (module.js:488:32) at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12) at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3) at Module.require
>   (module.js:498:17) at require (internal/module.js:20:19) at
>   file:///H:/electric/views/login.html:2:3

```
const electron = require('electron');
const {Menu} = require('electron');
const {app} = require('electron');
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const conn = require('mysql');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

// const app = electron.app;
// const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
var mainWindow = null;
app.on('ready', function () {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1024, height: 768, backgroundcolor: '#2e2c29' });
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: 'popupcheck.html',
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));enter code here
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    mainWindow.setProgressBar(1);
});`][1]
```

Comment: add the error printed by the app plz.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (H:\electric\main.js:12:4)
    at Object.<anonymous> (H:\electric\main.js:63:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at file:///H:/electric/views/login.html:2:3

Answer (score 24):

I guess you are trying to run electron using node. Does your package.json look like this?

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node main.js"
    }
}
```

please change to run electron app like this

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron ."
    }
}
```

It should work

**note:** this is extra for somebody that install electron to global with command something like this

```
npm install -g electron
```

when you want to use electron in the code **require(electron)**  you should link the global path to your current directory by using this command

```
npm link electron
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd need to see your html to be sure, but i had this problem and it was caused by linking the js in my html. Basically, you're starting the app twice. Once, when node runs 'electron whatever.js' when you start, and again because it's linked in your html. eg:

my app is being created in index.js, index.html is what my app is loading.

index.html has "

> script src="index.js"

", so it's firing off twice.

I commented out the script and i no longer got the error.

Comment: Thanks. It was just that. I think they both came from a terrible, horrible and disastrous tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

I have actually run into the same issue. I learned that you can only require(electon) once, or else it will only be defined for the last variable that called it. Instead of doing this:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const {Menu} = require('electron');
const {app} = require('electron');
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
```

Do this:

```
const { Menu, app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. On my machine I have to use

`npm start`

instead of the electron command or it gives me trouble.

Thanks [kontrollanten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7434393/kontrollanten)

Answer (score 1):

I'm real late to the game, but spent a while googling before i realized my terrible mistake.

I named my entry JavaScript file as electron.js, and that's what was breaking everything.

that means that my entry *electron.js* was referring/requiring ITSELF instead of the one in node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, app is not defined. Which means:

```
const {app} = require('electron');
```

Can not find the requirement you asked for. Are you sure you installed electron to appropriate folder / at all?

Run in project or module root:

```
npm list --depth=0
```

to get a list of your node packages.

Is electron there? If not:

```
npm install electron (with or without an optional flag --save)
```

from project root folder.

If flag is used requirement will be stored in package.json and when `npm install` is used electron will be locally installed in your node_modules folder.

You can also take a look at electron's npm documentation (same can be done with every npm module - results my vary in quality tho):
[npm - electron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron)

Comment: still not getting the solution... I created another folder and installed electron again while my node is installed globally and electron is installed in my app... I am getting the same error... how can I resolve this?

Comment: How are you starting your app? Do you run the `electron` command?

Comment: Also check if an `electron` folder exists under `node_modules` in your project root. If not, run `npm install` and check again

Answer (score 0):

I checked my html file. The problem was I have included my javascript files twice. Once in the package.json file and the second time in html. So, I have removed the javascript included from html. Thus, the issue is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove this old package and install this one if you didn't installed yet:

```
git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
cd electron-quick-start
npm install
npm start
```

if you got the same error then do the fix yourself :

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = require('app');
const BrowserWindow = require('browser-window')
```