# Electron: can't access main.js from another .js file

Tags: node.js, electron

I have all my html handlers in a second file (b.js). They look like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  let btn = window.getElementById('btn');
  button.addEventListener('click', fn);
}
```

This works fine, but I want to make a button to open another window, so I tried adding an exported method in main.js. My full main.js is below:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
let mainWindow;

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    frame: false,
    transparent: true,
    resizable: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    }
  });
  mainWindow.setResizable(false);
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow.quit();
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

module.exports = {
  openMainScreen: function () {
    mainWindow.loadFile("mainScreen.html");
    mainWindow.resizeTo(1200, 800);
  }
};
```

If I try to `require(main.js)`in `b.js` as I thought I should: I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

Pointing to `app.on('ready'...`. Looking at this post: [Cannot read property 'on' of undefined in electron javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977296/cannot-read-property-on-of-undefined-in-electron-javascript?rq=1) It says the app is starting twice. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why does `b.js` need to require `main.js`? When you require, its going to invoke all the code.. you would have to also wrap the default code in a method an export that too, then your have control on invoking it from b.js, but then b.js might as well be main.js :/

Comment: Why not use the api? https://electronjs.org/docs/api/window-open

Comment: @LawrenceCherone The reason b.js needs to require main.js is that I need to have access to "mainWindow" to update it's size and load a new html file to display.

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed this was to use electrons built in IPCmain to communicate between javascript that was being rendered with the html and the main javascript that ran the app.
https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main