# Cannot use exports and imports in Electron.js

Tags: javascript, electron

Here is my main (index.js) file:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron")

var mainWindow = null

app.on("ready", () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500,
        "webPreferences": {
            "nodeIntegration": true,
            "contextIsolation": false
        }
    })

    mainWindow.loadFile("src/html/welcome.html")
})
```

Now, I cannot use import/exports.

Whenever I am adding an export statement below the above code, it gives an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')`

If I remove the export/import lines, it works fine, as expected

(index.js)

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron")

var mainWindow = null

app.on("ready", () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500,
        "webPreferences": {
            "nodeIntegration": true,
            "contextIsolation": false
        }
    })

    mainWindow.loadFile("src/html/welcome.html")
})

module.exports.updateFunction = (_name) => {
    console.log(_name)
}
```

another.js

```
const { updateFunction } = require("../../index");

updateFunction("Hellow")
```

[image: My File Structure]

Comment: In what line do you get an error when you do what exactly? Not sure if I follow your problem

Comment: I have mentioned that. Whenever I am adding an export statement and use import in another, electron gives that error (mentioned). Although I can see that my page is actually rendered, but when i console logged out just a sample text, i doesnt work as expected.

Comment: I was recently stuck at the same error and discontinued with my project :(

Comment: So sad to hear that. Hope you can get the solution too.

Comment: Ah I see. I think your problem may that you are exporting from your index.js. I cannot say for sure without knowing your file structure, but when index.js is your entrypoint it is a circular dependency.

Comment: The real question here is what would compel you to write an export statement in the bootstrap file and then import that file when it has already been used to bootstrap your app?

Comment: I have multiple html files and want to show them one after the another on every button click (in short). Now that I found that remote was removed from electron >= v14.0.1 and moved to ```@electron/remote```, I switched over to that but couldnt figure out how to use that. I followed the doucmentation but still, I wasnt able to do that. I even added a question but no one gave an answer.

Comment: As in `index.js` loads all the other scripts, one of them `another.js` depends itself on index.js. But index.js is not loaded yet and js gets confused. Try moving your exports into another file? You can also try a circular dependency analyzer like [dpdm](https://github.com/acrazing/dpdm)

Comment: @AramBecker, I have added my file structure.

Comment: @AramBecker, what do you mean by ```Try moving your exports into another file```. If i move the function to other, I wnont be able to use the BrowserWindow view.

Comment: @AsianCat Why not? You can use imports and exports in every file except your entrypoint. Since your entrypoint (index.js) is used to start your application, or doesn't make sense to export anything from it. You can however export from other files and import them into your index.js

Comment: Unless you're building a library that is. In that case exporting from your entrypoint does make sense, since this is usually the file that is loaded by require calls of the library consumers

Comment: Is this your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46977296/5249411

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'on' of undefined in electron javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977296/cannot-read-property-on-of-undefined-in-electron-javascript)

Comment: The second link, I saw the answer with most votes. I am having a "start" command set to "electron ."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237235/discussion-between-aram-becker-and-asian-cat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is happening here is that you are creating a circular dependency for yourself. It might help whe you try to follow the path the module loader is taking (or trying to take) when loading your modules:

- Electron loads your entry point `index.js`

  - your entrypoint loads all your used submodules

    - the submodule `another.js` loads your entry point module `index.js`

At this point `index.js` is not completely loaded as all its dependencies have to load first. The circular dependency leaves the module loader in an undefined state, which depending on it's implementation can result in all sorts of errors. Usually it's along the lines of

```
some.stuff is not a function
Cannot read property `XXX` of undefined
`XXX` does not exist
undefined index `#` of `XXX`
```

There are ways to get around these errors, but the easiest approach is to avoid circular dependencies. In your case it would probably be easiest to create a module that both your `another.js` and your `index.js` can import from:

```js
// someModule.js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron")

let mainWindow = null

app.on("ready", () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500,
        "webPreferences": {
            "nodeIntegration": true,
            "contextIsolation": false
        }
    })

    mainWindow.loadFile("src/html/welcome.html")
})

// you can export mainWindow if you need it
module.exports.mainWindow = mainWindow;

module.exports.updateFunction = (_name) => {
    console.log(_name)
}
```

```js
// index.js
const { mainWindow } = require('someModule');
```

```js
// another.js
const { updateFunction } = require("../../someModule");

updateFunction("Hellow")
```

I would also recommend using [Es6-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) imports and exports as they are much easier to comprehend, but that's a different story.