# Unexpected token import in Angular2 CLI express server.ts

Tags: angular, express, typescript, angular-cli

I'm starting an Angular2 Application and I'm setting up my server using express and Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.25.5

In this kind of file structure:

```
project root
|-server
  |-server.ts
|-src
  |-app
```

When I run `nodemon server.ts`

I get the following error:

[image]

`import`s are working elsewhere in my `app` though, so I'm not sure what the issue is. I'm also not getting any vs code errors to suggest that any thing was imported incorrectly. Also both `express` and `body-parser` have been `npm install --save`ed as well as the `@types/express` (`--save-dev`). **What is preventing this import statement form working and how can I correct the issue?**

**server.ts**

```
import * as express from 'express';
import {Application} from 'express';
import {apiFoods} from './api/apiFoods';

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app: Application = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

apiFoods(app);

app.listen(8090, () => {
    console.log('Server is now running on port 8090 ...');
});
```

Comment: what if you try to import express = require('express');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying issue here is that the `import` statement is an ES6 command that is not recognized by node. The solution that I found to use [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) to transpile my typescript first and then run it.

```
npm install --save-dev ts-node
```

and then add a new script to use it in your `package.json`

**package.json**

```
"scripts":{
  "api-server": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./server/server.ts"
}
```

When you want to execute run:

```
npm run api-server
```

To watch using `nodemon`, I execute ([taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979489/how-to-watch-and-reload-ts-node-when-typescript-file-changes)):

```
nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --ignore 'src/**/*.spec.ts' --exec './node_modules/.bin/ts-node' server/server.ts
```

Comment: conventionally the `server` folder is placed under `src` next to `app`

Comment: Note that instead of `./node_modules/.bin/ts-node`, you should be able to just write `ts-node`. This is because the `.bin` directory is automatically checked for you.

Answer (score 3):

Either update node to 7.x to get native es6 support or use babel-node with nodemon like this;

```
nodemon -w --exec "babel-node server.ts"
```

You can also specify which folders you want to watch for changes by adding a folder name after -w like `-w server`

To get babel-node to work, you have to install babel-preset-es2015

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
```

and create a file named .babelrc next to your package.json file with the following content

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Comment: Can you clear this up for me: why must I use babel when typescript is already installed? I don't understand the underlying issue. The example that I am mimicking has no `.babelrc`

Comment: this is the repo https://github.com/angular-university/ngrx-course/blob/master/package.json

Comment: .babelrc is the options used by babel when it transpiles the code. you can also add the options on the package file. read more at https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/ . Note, it is not needed to transpile the code if you use node v.7, so the author of the code in the repo might have the latest version of node. It might be the reason it works without the options for him, but not you