# Live compiling Typescript to es5 and immediate run

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

So recently I've decided to try to rewrite one of my "little" projects from es5 to Typescript. It's a Node.js Rest api based on express.js.

Is there a way how to recompile a TS project into a **single file** on change and primarily also **run** the app?

When using react/es6 I'm using webpack dev server, which can recompile on change pretty quickly. When using es5 in node.js I'm using nodemon, which  immediately re-runs the code on change. But how to properly combine these two functionalities? Should I use webpack to compile TS code? But is webpack capable of also running the code?

I've seen an example of [using the ts compiler with nodemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979489/how-to-watch-and-reload-ts-node-when-typescript-file-changes), but using this way it's not possible to create one single output bundle.

```
src
  |- entryPoint.ts
  |- routes
  |    |- foo.ts
  |    |- bar.ts
  |    |- ...
  |- schemas
  |    |- foo.ts
  |    |- bar.ts
  |    |- ...
  |- ...
dist
  |- singleOutputBundle.js
tsconfig.json
nodemon.json
webpack.config.js
package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

First, install the loader for typescript

`npm i -D awesome-typescript-loader`

In your webpack config file, add these

```
"entry": "./src/entryPoint.ts",
"output": {
    "filename": "singleOutputBundle.js",
    "path": __dirname + "/dist"
},
"resolve": {
    "extensions:[".ts",".js"],
},
"module": {
    "rules": [
         {
             "test": /\.ts$/,
             "use": "awesome-typescript-loader",
             "exclude": "/node_modules/"
         }
    ]
}
```

This will configure webpack to transpile ts code for you, the rest you just configure as normal

Comment: Thanks. In the end, I had to use this solution. But as I wrote, this solution doesn't includes running the compiled code. You can't even use a webpack-dev-server alongside with nodemon, because it's not effecting a filesystem, so nodemon has nothing to watch or run.
And just one note to your config, it should also contain "target": "node", otherwise the webpack will probably have issues with importing some modules (like fs or net).
Unfortunately, I guess there's no good solution to this yet...