# Nodemon not reloading. What's wrong with this nodemon.json file

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemon

This is my nodemon.json

```
{ 
    "watch": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "exec": "node out/index.js" 
}
```

I run the nodemon by executing:

```
nodemon
```

In root nodejs directory

This is output:

```
 % nodemon                                                                                                     
[nodemon] 1.11.0                                                                                
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`                                                                                                                       
[nodemon] watching: src/**/*.ts                                                                                                                       
[nodemon] starting node out/index.js
Yay! Started app!
```

But when I edit any ts file in src nodemon doesn't restart the app.

**UPDATE**

Running `nodemon --watch src/index.ts --exec 'node out/index.js'`

Works and reloads the app on modifying index.ts

However, running with wildcard

`nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --exec 'node out/index.js'`

or

`nodemon --watch src --exec 'node out/index.js'`

Doesn't reload the app.

Comment: You will need a `ts-node` package. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979489/how-to-watch-and-reload-ts-node-when-typescript-file-changes/37979548

Comment: I have started with the link you provided, but it doesn't work for me, therefore I started simplifiying the script and eventually ended up with that one. But it also doesn't work

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**Solved!**

By running nodemon in verbose mode I have discovered that **by default it watches only *.js** files, **regardless** of what wildcard you are watching. Therefore adding `-e ts` to the command fixes the problem:

```
nodemon --watch src/ --exec 'node out/index.js' -e ts
```

If someone uses `nodemon.json` here is mine after fix:

```
{ 
    "watch": ["src"],
    "exec": "tsc && node out/index.js" ,
    "ext": "js, json, ts, proto"
}
```

Comment: Watching for js files in the `out` directory would make more sense if you're executing `node out/index.js`

Comment: nodemon.json
```{
  "watch": ["src/*", "package.json"],
  "ext": "ts js json"
}
```
in package.json
{
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon -r source-map-support/register ."
},
}

when run with `yarn start`
you will get
```$ nodemon -r source-map-support/register .
[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter rs
[nodemon] watching path(s): src/**/* lb3app/server/**/* package.json
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,js,json
[nodemon] starting node -r source-map-support/register .
Server is running at http://127.0.0.1::3000```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any luck with src/ watching either. I'm watching files via `nodemon --watch '**/*'` this will finds any changes in  the nested files

Answer (score -1):

Use `single quotation` for multi-value args like `--exec' in the package.json script.

e.g. I changed `"nodemon --exec npm run build-langs"` to `"nodemon --exec 'npm run build-langs'"` and worked.