# How to run nodemon + ts-node + typescript altogether without having to install ts-node or npx globally?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemon, ts-node

I have the following in my `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve-fake-api": "nodemon fake-api/server.ts --watch 'fake-api/*.*'",
    "serve-vue": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "serve": "concurrently -k \"npm run serve-fake-api\" \"npm run serve-vue\"",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
```

and I would like to rewrite `"serve-fake-api": "nodemon --exec 'ts-node' fake-api/server.ts --watch fake-api/*.*",` but without having to install `ts-node` or `npx` globally.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come across [`ts-node-dev`](https://github.com/whitecolor/ts-node-dev) recently, which fuses together [`ts-node`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) and [`node-dev`](https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev).

No configuration required. CLI arguments are the combination of the ones `ts-node` and `node-dev` accepts, and a couple of its own on top of that.

Run like this:

```
"start": "tsnd fake-api/server.ts"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just install `nodemon` and `ts-node` locally as dev dependency:

```
npm install -D ts-node nodemon
```

And then run

```
nodemon -x 'node -r ts-node/register' fake-api/server.ts --watch 'fake-api/*.*'
```

Now, when you run npm scripts they will use your [local version by default](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script#description):

> In addition to the shell’s pre-existing PATH, npm run adds
> node_modules/.bin to the PATH provided to scripts. Any binaries
> provided by locally-installed dependencies can be used without the
> node_modules/.bin prefix

Comment: They were already installed as dev dependencies and npm does seem to see "ts-node" =/

Comment: `[0] [nodemon] starting 'ts-node' fake-api/server.ts` => 
`[0] ''ts-node'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

Comment: That's a weird behaviour. Try to update your `serve-fake-api` script to `nodemon -x 'node -r ts-node/register' fake-api/server.ts --watch 'fake-api/*.*'`

Comment: thanks there is something weird, actually anything that comes after --exec like node ts-node is not found. `[0] [nodemon] starting `'node -r ts-node/register' fake-api/server.ts`` =>
`[0] ''node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` => 
`[0] operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Looks like something similar to: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/389

Answer (score 2):

I managed to run everything with the `packages.json` below:

```
{
  "name": "rm-combo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve-fake-api": "nodemon fake-api/index.ts --watch fake-api/*.*",
    "serve-vue": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "serve": "concurrently -k \"npm run serve-fake-api\" \"npm run serve-vue\"",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^12.12.7",
    "axios": "~0.19.0",
    "devextreme": "19.2.3",
    "devextreme-vue": "19.2.3",
    "element-ui": "~2.8.2",
    "oidc-client": "~1.9.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.3.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.1.10",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2",
    "vuex-class": "^0.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
    "@types/json-server": "^0.14.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.0.5",
    "concurrently": "^5.0.0",
    "devextreme-cldr-data": "^1.0.2",
    "globalize": "^1.4.2",
    "json-server": "^0.15.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.5.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
```

and ts features supported with doing that trick there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59126595/4636721