# TypeScript: "Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects" error in development environment

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nodemon

### Problem

When I'm trying to start my development environment with `npm run dev:server` I'm getting this error:

```
return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/routes/snippets.ts:6:26 - error TS2695: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.

6 exports.snippetRouter = (0, express_1.Router)();
```

and then server crashes. But when I run `npm run build` project compiles without any errors. I can then run `node build/server.js` and everything works as it should. I'm also not getting any errors or warnings in my editor.

I looked for similar errors but couldn't find anything matching my case.

Any ideas what can I try to fix that?

It's also worth mentioning that if I comment/delete `app.use('/api/snippets', snippetRouter)` line from `server.ts` and run `npm run dev:server` everything works correctly (except for the missing functionality of course).

### Project

Project structure:

```
src
├── controllers
|   └── snippets.ts
├── middleware
│   ├── index.ts
|   └── asyncWrapper.ts
├── routes
|   └── snippets.ts
└── server.ts
```

**controllers/snippets.ts**

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { asyncWrapper } from '../middleware';

export const createSnippet = asyncWrapper(
  async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
    res.status(201).json({
      data: "test msg"
    });
  }
);
```

**middleware/asyncWrapper.ts**

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

type Foo = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void>;

export const asyncWrapper =
  (foo: Foo) => (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    return Promise.resolve(foo(req, res, next)).catch(next);
  };
```

**routes/snippets.ts**

```js
import { Router } from 'express';
import { createSnippet } from '../controllers/snippets';

export const snippetRouter = Router();

snippetRouter.route('/').post(createSnippet);
```

**server.ts**

```js
import express from 'express';
import { snippetRouter } from './routes/snippets';

const app = express();
app.use('/api/snippets', snippetRouter);

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Server is working');
});
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "snippet-hub",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/server.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "init:client": "npm install --prefix=client",
    "init:server": "npm install",
    "init": "npm-run-all -n init:**",
    "dev:client": "npm start --prefix=client",
    "dev:server": "nodemon src/server.ts",
    "dev": "npm-run-all -n --parallel dev:**",
    "build:clear": "rm -rf build",
    "build:tsc": "tsc",
    "build": "npm-run-all -n build:**"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^16.9.2",
    "@types/validator": "^13.6.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.5",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2",
    "umzug": "^3.0.0-beta.16"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: Can you show the complete **package.json**?

Comment: @tromgy Updated my original post

Comment: You are somehow running the typescript compiler on your *output* js files ( i think)

Comment: @Evert, this is an interesting hypothesis.

Comment: @PaulUlibro, unfortunately I can't reproduce the problem with exactly same dependencies.

Comment: @tromgy I have also added my **tsconfig.json** file. Can you try again with my configuration?

Comment: @Evert I ran `rm -rf build && cd src` and `ts-node server.ts` and it still didn't work even without transpiled code.

Comment: I doubt that this is the issue, but `main` at the very least should refer to your generated .js file, not the .ts file.

Comment: Did you configured your nodemon? If you did please provide the nodemon configuration. Otherwise I would purpose you to follow the instructions from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979489/how-to-watch-and-reload-ts-node-when-typescript-files-change

Comment: @Max I just created nodemon config as in the instructions but it didn't change anything. I doubt it's the problem with nodemon because running `ts-node src/server.ts` directly also throws the same error and nodemon is completely omitted here.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that if I comment/delete `app.use('/api/snippets', snippetRouter)` line from `server.ts` and run `npm run dev:server` everything works correctly (except for the missing functionality of course).

Comment: @PaulUlibro, still works for me with your tsconfig.json

Comment: @PaulUlibro Have you tried removing **node_modules** and **package-lock.json** and doing fresh **npm install**?

Answer (score 0):

I had same error, how I did to fix it was to import express and not destructure it then call the router from express. Adjusting file `routes/snippets.ts` to below fixed the issue

```
import express from 'express';
export const snippetRouter = express.Router();

snippetRouter.route('/').post(createSnippet);
```

Above solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue when i was using an arrow function by returning a key value pair object  surrounded by {}. Below is the code when the issue occured

```
const methodTest=(value)=>{ key1 : value,key2:value }
```

solution is to add a () around the braces {} example : below is the solution worked for me

```
const methodTest=(value)=>({key1:value , key2:value })
```

Comment: Hi, please add supporting infos...Docs, or explain why this works. Please read  [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thank you!